# SQL Server - Error converting data type nvarchar to bigint

Tags: sql, sql-server

When I run following query with `SELECT *` I get error saying :

> [S0005][8114] Error converting data type nvarchar to bigint.

```
SELECT * FROM (
                SELECT * , ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY CAST(id as BIGINT)) AS RowNum
                FROM users
            ) AS users
            WHERE users.RowNum BETWEEN 0 AND 5 ;
```

When I run this query only with `SELECT id , ROW_NUMBER() ...` everything works.

My DB looks like this:

[image: Image of database]

This query run well with other table where `id` column is `NVARCHAR`

ID column is number only and if i cast it as : CAST(id as NVARCHAR) i get same error.

EDIT:

I Found problem with column ID values

ID 46903836
ID 9100000004

Small ids dont have leading zeros

Comment: No need to cast ID as `BIGINT`, if it's already a `BIGINT`. You only need to cast it if it is `NVARCHAR`. If by any chance you have a letter in your `ID` field, because it's `NVARCHAR`, then there's no way you can convert to a numeric.

Comment: Well the error message is pretty clear. You have a value in your varchar that is not a valid bigint. This is why you should always use the correct datatype.

Comment: why you cast ID as BIGINT if in your image ID is BIGINT?

Comment: I have a feeling you're doing something wrong, and what you're showing us is not the actual cause of the error. I think some details are lost on the way... Are you sure you're not connected to two databases and querying them differently? Rest assured that your query isn't wrong, it's the data in the column or the datatype.

Comment: Unless OP is experimenting with the window functions (always encouraged)  seems like a long way to go  Select top 5 ... Order by ID

Answer (score 8):

Usually when I get this error it is because there is whitespace on the front or end of the column. Here is how I fix it.

```
SELECT * FROM (
            SELECT * , ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY CAST(LTRIM(RTRIM(id)) as BIGINT)) AS RowNum
            FROM users
        ) AS users
        WHERE users.RowNum BETWEEN 0 AND 5 ;
```

This will ensure ID is just the number only I am also assuming that there aren't any alpha characters with the ID.

Comment: Trailing spaces almost never matter for comparisons (where / having) and especially conversions. Do you have an example where a certain number of leading or trailing spaces caused a conversion error?

Comment: I don't, but I have had trouble casting or converting a NVARCHAR or VARCHAR to a numeric datatype when there are spaces in the string.

Comment: In the middle perhaps (which wouldn't be solved with the trim), but I've never seen leading or trailing cause this. was just wondering since your answer alluded to the causation of this problem.

Comment: @scsimon: Just try `SELECT ISNUMERIC('2')` and then try again with a new line after the 2. (`\r\n`). The first is true and the second is false and the same would cause an error when converting

Comment: @HugoDelsing that’s not a space. That’s a carriage return / line feed. Way different.

Comment: Yes it is, I agree. But even though mssql does not remove it with `trim`, the same method in other languages does. So to avoid confusion I mentioned it. So while I agree that the above example could/should never work, it does provide the necessary information to solve the issue.

Answer (score 2):

You Don't need to cast your id column as it is already in bigint datatype

[image: SQL server database]]

Comment: but if there other col in table for example name,email etc.. you will get that error.

Answer (score 1):

Your `ID` field is `BIGINT` (you have posted your table structure), this don't cause the error in your question.

But, because is unuseful the `CAST` you can rewrite your query as follow:

```
SELECT * FROM (
    SELECT * , ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY id) AS RowNum
    FROM users
) AS users
WHERE users.RowNum BETWEEN 0 AND 5 ;
```

Comment: While true, it doesn't explain the error which almost certainly isn't happening int he posted code snippet

Comment: i don't get that error when i am doing only 

SELECT * FROM (
    SELECT id , ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY id) AS RowNum
    FROM users
) AS users
WHERE users.RowNum BETWEEN 0 AND 5 ;

but i also need other columns like name,email etc...

Comment: If you want other columns, please post your complete request. Because was very strange the error linked to your question query.